# Jest: button handler click raises an error

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I try to test button handler click inside CampaignGride component but I get error by last three lines

```
it('should call onClick handler on click', () => {

    const props = {
        campaigns: testCampaigns,
        onBottomVisible: noop,
        onTopVisible: noop,
        seasonInfo: {season: '2018AW'},
        weeks: testWeeks,
        isoCalendarWeek: new CalendarWeek('2019-W52'),
        onClick: jest.fn()
    };

    const wrapper = shallow(<CampaignGrid {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(ButtonAddCampaign).length).toBe(1);

    expect(props.onClick.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
    wrapper.find(ButtonAddCampaign).simulate('click');
    expect(props.onClick.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    expect(props.onClick.mock.calls[0].length).toBe(1);
    expect(props.onClick.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(new CalendarWeek('2019-W52'));
});
```

Comment: components.CampaignGrid › should call onClick handler on click

    expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      1
    Received:
      0

Comment: can you share 'CampaignGrid' code ?